# Pass User input as argument in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

From nas-yahoo_stock

I would like to get the user's input from the command-line, and pass it as an argument, which returns the stock quote.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yahoo_stock'

print "Stock Symbol: "
symbol = gets

quote = YahooStock::Quote.new(:stock_symbols => ['YHOO', "symbol"])
puts quote.results.output
```

When I input "YHOO" at the command-line the output returned is "3/10/2011",17.08 (which is great) and "N/A",0.00 (not so great), respectively. Obviously I missed something simple. I tried @symbol with no luck, and I can't find any related answers.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Take the quotes off of `"symbol"`

Comment: Also, may want to do a `chomp` on that input to strip out any newlines.  e.g. `symbol.chomp`.